# Parse - Calling cloud code on app installation

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, cloud

I have created some cloud code for my Parse database and I want it to be called when the a user installs the app. I have implemented Push so I want it to get triggered when the user registers for Push Notifications.  I also want to be able to pass the "deviceToken" into my cloud function.

Here is the function that I have so far:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("newListing", function(request, response) {
                   var ListingClass = Parse.Object.extend("Listings");
                   var listing = new ListingClass();

                   listing.set("Name","--");
                   listing.set("DeviceID",request.params.param_DeviceID);

                   listing.save(null,{
                               success:function(listing) {
                               response.success(listing);
                               },
                               error:function(error) {
                               response.error(error);
                               }
                               });
});
```

Summary:

- I want to call the cloud function "newListing" when the user registers for Push Notifications

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get the deviceToken when the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method is called in the AppDelegate, so place your cloud code calling function in there.

Swift code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
  // Do your normal token handling to set the device token in the Installation and save to Parse.com
  let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
  currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
  currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
  // Call your cloud code function
  let deviceTokenAsString = .... // You need to implement this code
  PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("newListing", withParameters: ["param_DeviceID": deviceTokenAsString]) { results, error in
    // Error handling, and any other functionality you need when your cloud function is complete
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a valid solution. However, I forgot to mention that I was trying to get this to work for an app that was already live and I didn't want to release a new version. So I was looking for a solution that would cause the cloud code to be executed without modifying the existing project. I found a solution and will be posting it as an alternate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution that I came up with that didn't require the app to be modified. This cloud function gets called after a new installation occurs.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {
                      var newID = request.object.get("deviceToken");

                      var query = new Parse.Query("Listings");
                      query.equalTo("DeviceID", newID);
                      query.find({
                         success: function(results) {
                             if(results.length > 0){
                                 response.success("ID already exists");
                             }else{
                                 var ListingClass = Parse.Object.extend("Listings");
                                 var listing = new ListingClass();

                                 listing.set("Name","--");
                                 listing.set("DeviceID",newID);

                                 listing.save(null,{
                                              success:function(listing) {
                                              response.success(listing);
                                              },
                                              error:function(error) {
                                              response.error(error);
                                              }
                                              });
                             }
                         },
                         error: function() {
                             response.error("ID fail");
                         }
                     });
});
```